# A word like "confession" for relating personal details but lacking connotations of guilt?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

> The writings here are my confessions.

is essentially what I mean to say, minus the implication of guilt, or, with more words,

> The writings here describe personal details about myself and my thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try *[divulgence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divulgence)*:

> to make known (as a confidence or secret)

So:

> The writings herein are my divulgences.

Answer (score 0):

> [**memoir**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/memoir)
>   1. An account of the personal experiences of an author
>   2.  often **memoirs**. An autobiography.

e.g. *a retired politician who is writing his memoirs*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoir) (as always) has an article on its usage and history

> **Memoir** (from French: *mémoire*: *memoria*, meaning memory or reminiscence), is a literary nonfiction genre. More specifically, it
>   is a collection of memories that an individual writes about moments or
>   events, both public or private that took place in the author's life.

Answer (score 0):

[revelation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revelation):

> an act of making something known : an act of revealing something in usually a surprising way

[disclosure](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disclosure):

> the act of making something known : the act of disclosing something

Answer (score 0):

Another thought, if memoir wasn't what you were looking for:

> The writings here are my self-reflections.

Answer (score 0):

> “I want to write, but more than that, I want to bring out all kinds of things that lie buried deep in my heart.” 
> ― Anne Frank

Answer (score 0):

The [**apologia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apologia) is a type of writing that, in the classical sense, is essentially a confession without shame or guilt. It is a piece that is written to explain or justify one's beliefs or actions([2](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apologia)), and to persuade others that those beliefs or actions are right or reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

[Expound](https://www.etymonline.com/word/expound):

> "put forth, expose, exhibit;" from ex- "forth" + ponere "to put, place"

Expound generally has a sense that you're going past a introductory summary and giving a deeper explanation into the details of something.  It is often on a general subject but one could expound on one's thoughts or memories.